# I'm using C# in studio code, how to get content from checked column in listview?

Tags: c#, listview, checkbox

I'm using C# in studio code, now I created a form with listview, I added columns and checkboxes in the listview, and I want to ask how to extract the content of the first column from the checked row.

I tried to search for ways online but none of them work I guess..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to extract data you can try the following:

- First, you need to get a reference to the listview control. You can
  do this by using the FindControl method or by using the ID property
  of the listview.
- Next, you can use the CheckedItems property of the listview to get a
  collection of all the checked rows.
- You can then use a foreach loop to iterate through each checked row
  in the collection.
- For each checked row, you can use the SubItems property of the
  ListViewItem to get a collection of all the subitems (columns) in the
  row.

  You can then use the Text property of the first subitem (column) in
  the collection to get the content of the first column.

Short example:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listview1.CheckedItems)
{
    string firstColumnText = item.SubItems[0].Text;
    // Do something with the firstColumnText value here
}
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much, it is working!! (Even though i don't really understand how HAHA), do you have any recommended websites for me to learn this? I'm a beginner in c#.